# CakePHP: How to write a find() query that excludes one field in the resultset?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

Is there a way to write a CakePHP query to return all fields (columns) except one via `find()`?  Or do I need to use the `fields` parameter and actually list all the fields, except the excluded field?

For example, if I have a database table (model), Company, with these fields:

```
id
name
street
city
state
zip
phone
```

Normally, `$this->Company->find('all')` would return all the fields.  I want to exclude the phone field from the resultset.

Comment: You can get the fields via `$this->Company-schema()`. Then use the array keys which are the available field names, remove your undesired fields, and you got your fields array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of a couple ways to do this

1. Write out all the fields you want to include in the fields parameter.  As mentioned in the comment, you can use $this->Company->schema to get all the fields programmatically rather than writing them out.
2. Unset the field you don't want after you get the data.  You can do this in the model's afterFind function too.

Comment: I'm not familiar with what #2 is. Are you talking about unsetting the undesired element in the array returned by Model::schema() and then passing that as the 'fields' parameter of Model::find()?

Comment: No, I was saying, you could just get everything, then call unset($data['Company']['unwanted_field']).  Obviously though this solution doesn't help if the reason you're trying to do this is if you want to not get that data in the first place, rather than not having that data in your results.

Answer (score 7):

```
$fields = array_keys($this->Company->getColumnTypes());
$key = array_search('phone', $fields);
unset($fields[$key]);
$this->Company->find('all', array('fields' => $fields));
```

For more info, please have a look at http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/additional-methods-and-properties.html#model-getcolumntypes

Comment: I'm only on CakePHP 1.3 at the moment, but thanks for the information.